# Reactjs - flipcard - finetuning animation and control

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an application that features the React Flipcard module -- but I noticed the flipcard won't flip back in some situations where the user hovers off too quickly -- I've tried to put in the state - not just isFlipped - but is flipping state - so to avoid triggering the flip multiple times if the item is still flipping --- but also I got a timeout to reverse back to the frontcard so the front comes back.

Is there a way to improve the quality and process to this flipcard.

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-morning-duo0k?file=/src/FlipIconCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactCardFlip from 'react-card-flip';
import './FlipIconCard.scss';

class FlipIconCard extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
        this.state = {
        isFlipped: false
      };
      this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
      this.resetToFront = this.resetToFront.bind(this);
    }

    handleToggle(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState(prevState => ({ isFlipped: !prevState.isFlipped }));

      this.setState({ isFlippping: true });
      if(this.state.isFlippping){
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                this.setState({ isFlippping: false });
            }
            .bind(this), 600
        );
      }

      if(!this.state.isFlippping){
        this.resetToFront();
      }
    }

    resetToFront() {
      let timer = setTimeout(
          function() {
            if(this.state.isFlipped) {
              this.setState({ isFlipped: false });
              clearTimeout(this.state.timer);
            }
          }
          .bind(this), 4000
      );
      this.setState({ timer: timer });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="flip-icon-card">
            <div className="flip-icon-flipper">
              <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
                <div onMouseOver={this.handleToggle}>
                  <div className="flip-card-contents"><img className="icon-badge" src={require('../../../img/icons/'+this.props.icon)} alt="" /></div>
                </div>         
                <div onMouseLeave={this.handleToggle}>
                  <div className="flip-card-contents backcard"><div className="element">{this.props.text}</div></div>
                </div>
              </ReactCardFlip>
            </div>
            <div>{this.props.label}</div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FlipIconCard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kinda overcomplicated this, you could define a function that receives a flag and set the state correspondingly:

```js
setFlipped(flipped) {
  this.setState({ isFlipped: flipped });
}
```

And on the wrapper, register the events like this:

```js
<div
  className="flip-icon-flipper"
  onMouseLeave={() => this.setFlipped(false)}
  onMouseOver={() => this.setFlipped(true)}
>
```

Here's the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-tharp-kycle?file=/src/FlipIconCard.js)

Comment: right -- but there is a stance - where the onMouseLeave doesn't get triggered - and as such the card's back remains shown forever

Comment: @TheOldCounty This rarely happens, actually never. Unless the user's cursor is still on that card. You can try to play around the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-tharp-kycle?file=/src/FlipIconCard.js), you'll never make a card filp over without you cursor is still hovering on it.

Comment: The reason your approach is having this issue is because you registered the events on different sides. Which before the card completely flips over, there's no way to trigger the `onMouseLeave` on the other side.

Comment: -- good solve -- I was also wondering if its this prev state toggling.

Comment: that's why I had this resetToFront function to try and switch back

Comment: Thanks - I've implemented your solution